# latest version pyarrow can't serialize and deserialize? (module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'serialize')

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, serialization, google-cloud-storage, pyarrow

I want my bigquery table data saving GCS to an arrow file(.arrow):

```py
import pyarrow as pa    
query = f"""
    SELECT * FROM `{table_path}.{table_id}`
    """
    query_results = b_client.query(query).result()


table = query_results.to_arrow()
serialized_table = pa.serialize(table).to_buffer().to_pybytes()
```

This is my original method but after upgrading my pyarrow version I get error for `serialize()`:

```
AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'serialize'
```

How can I resolve this?

Also in GCS my arrow file has 130000 rows and 30 columns And `.arrow` file size is 60MB. When I receive a request then I return data that reads GCS. But it is too slow. It takes like 30 seconds.
How to make it faster? like 10 seconds

Comment: serialize was deprecated in Arrow 12 and you should either use pickle or Arrow IPC instead. And you might consider breaking your question into multiple so it's less likely this one gets closed. It's generally good to ask one question per post.

Comment: Note this was already deprecated in pyarrow 2.0 (2.5 years ago) and should have raised warnings, and was finally removed in 12.0